# Unable to compile Plotly charts from R sweave to pdf

Tags: r, latex, plotly

I'm unable to convert charts created by plotly in R sweave to Pdf. But other charts can be created. Is there any other additional code needs to be added for plotly charts?

Below is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}



<<echo = FALSE>>=
C1<-c("A","B","C")
C2<-c(10,20,30)
Df<-data.frame(C1,C2)
@

\begin {figure}

<<echo = FALSE, fig = TRUE>>=
suppressWarnings (library (plotly))
plot_ly(Df, x = ~C1, y = ~C2, type = "bar")%>% layout(title = "ABC")
@

 \caption {PlotlyChart}
 \end {figure}

 Normal Chart

\begin {figure}

<<echo = FALSE, fig = TRUE>>=
barplot(Df[ ,2], names.arg = Df[ ,1])
@

\caption {Normal_Chart}
\end {figure}

\end{document}
```

When I try a normal box plot in R, it works. Only when I add Plotly chart, I get an error message as

```
 Running pdflatex on ABC.tex...failed

 Error running /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (exit code 1)
```

I'm new to R sweave and Latex, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotly produces javascript code that draws the plot. This code is to be executed within a web browser. Plotly is usable when generating an HTML document only. No PDF, no Latex.

BUT you can use package `webshot` with `phantomjs` to save the plotly as an image, then include the image as a figure.

First install webshot:

```
install.packages("webshot")
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

Then modify you Sweave file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo = FALSE>>=
C1<-c("A","B","C")
C2<-c(10,20,30)
Df<-data.frame(C1,C2)
@

<<echo = FALSE, fig = FALSE>>=
suppressWarnings (library (webshot))
suppressWarnings (library (plotly))
py <- plot_ly(Df, x = ~C1, y = ~C2, type = "bar")%>% layout(title = "ABC")
export(py, file = "myplot.png")
@
\begin {figure}
\includegraphics{myplot.png}
\end {figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very interesting solution. Also of note, `phantomjs` works as a stand-alone terminal tool, which might be useful if you want to simply generate a static image of the Plotly HTML output. http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html